# Liquibase: insert blob files taking path from the input *.csv

Tags: xml, csv, liquibase

I'm working with Liquibase for the db population. 
Have one entity definition file with the field:

```
    <column name="image" type="longblob"></column>
```

And load-data configuration:

```
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8" file="images.csv"
            separator=";" tableName="images">
    </loadData>
```

In the input csv file I have 3 columns:
1) name
2) type
3) image

So my question is: is it possible to have in the input file field "image" filled with PATH to the image ("/test.png"), and in the db populate it as a BLOB uploading the image from provided in the *.cvs path?

Comment: Yes it's possible if your entity contains String image ;

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible.**

Simply use the path to the image file in CSV file in place where you have column for image data.

Like in this CSV file:

```
id,description,image
1,'just my image',/path/to/the/image
2,'nice image',/path/to/another/image
```

And you can define your liquibase changelog file like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="Johny.Walker">
        <loadData tableName="Image"
                  file="image_test_data.csv"
                  separator=","
                  quotchar="'"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```